# express-pouchdb relative module was not found

Tags: pouchdb

I am building a project with Electron, Vue, Typescript and rxdb.
As soon as I add the express-pouchdb package I get the message:

> This relative module was not found:
>
> - ../../package in ./node_modules/express-pouchdb/lib/routes/root.js

when trying to build the project.

The operating system is a MacOS 10.15.3

Answer (score 0):

That module was moved to pouchdb-server a while ago and is now at:

https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server

but if you are not trying to build a server then there are other PouchDb libraries that are more appropriate. I use pouchdb-node for writing Node.js routines that talk to CouchDb:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-node

so this might be a better choice for an Electron app.

It may also be that your relative path is wrong in your route - that has happened to me too - but I can't tell from the information you gave us.